# Mongoose Multi Connection with Fastify

Tags: node.js, mongoose, fastify

I am trying to use multiple database connections in fastify with mongoose.

for single db code looks like

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fastifyPlugin = require('fastify-plugin')
mongoose.Promise = Promise; // Set mongoose to use ES6 Promises.
const reconnectTimeout = 5000; // ms.
const db = mongoose.connection;

async function dbConnector1(fastify, options) {
    const conn1 = mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/db1", {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        retryWrites: false
    })
        .then(() => console.log( 'Connection to DB1 successful'))
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
};

module.exports = fastifyPlugin(dbConnector1,{
    name: 'DB1'
})
```

I have put the above code in conn1.js
I have created a similar connection with different db in conn2.js and in index.js I am registering the db plugin as follows

```
        await fastify.register(require('./src/db/conn1'))
        await fastify.register(require('./src/db/conn2'))
```

I get the following error -

**MongooseError: Can't call `openUri()` on an active connection with different connection strings. Make sure you aren't calling `mongoose.connect()` multiple times. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections**

[image]